# Make SQL Server Express available from outer network

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

How to make my local SQL Server Express (which part of Visual Studio) available from outer network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set it up to allow remote connections (not enabled by default for express editions). See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277) for details for SQL 2005.

Or [this article](http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/) for SQL 2008 instructions

Comment: Just as a FYI, the Surface Area Configuration has been discontinued in 2008, in 2008 you need to run Configuration Manager, then enable TCP/IP and remote connections

Comment: @SQLMenace - Thanks. I've added a SQL 2008 specific link in.